# ksh string comparison failing

Tags: shell, ksh

i have below code which is failing to compare two strings with equal value

```
    InptHeaderRow=$(head -1 $InptFileName)

    echo $(head -1 $InptFileName)

    echo $BaseHeaderRow

    if [[ "$BaseHeaderRow" = "$InptHeaderRow" ]]; then
            echo "<img class=\"message\" src=\"../images/success.png\">&nbsp&nbsp Valid Header Recond Found in $InptFileName"  | tee -a ${LOGFILE}
            CheckDelimetersInHeader
    else
            echo "<img class=\"message\" src=\"../images/error.png\">&nbsp&nbspNo Valid Header Record Found in $InptFileName"  | tee -a ${LOGFILE}
            echo "Exiting.."  | tee -a ${LOGFILE}
            exit 1
    fi
    }
```

output below

```
+ CheckHeader
SUBACC^AGENT^TRANCODE^VALUEDATE^ENTRYDATE^AMOUNT^TEXT10^SDE^REF1^REF2^REF3^STMT_DATE^STYP^SCO^STMTNO^STMT_PG^SIDE^OPBAL^OPBALCY^CLBAL^CLBALCY^OPBALTP^CLBALTP^ACCOWNRINFO
SUBACC^AGENT^TRANCODE^VALUEDATE^ENTRYDATE^AMOUNT^TEXT10^SDE^REF1^REF2^REF3^STMT_DATE^STYP^SCO^STMTNO^STMT_PG^SIDE^OPBAL^OPBALCY^CLBAL^CLBALCY^OPBALTP^CLBALTP^ACCOWNRINFO
<img class="message" src="../images/error.png">&nbsp&nbspNo Valid Header Record Found in /opt/tlm/ss_fin_prd/TLM27/datafeeds/GBLA42824140700000GBLA340C97000000000000_21012020.txt
Exiting..
```

not sure what is going wrong here

Comment: There are probably DOS line endings involved here (probably in the input file). One string ends with `\r`, the other does not.

Comment: great. that seems to the problem. any handy tips to remove ^M

Comment: `tr -d '\r'` will remove your `\r`s (aka `^M`, `0x0d`). Compare `printf 'foo\r\nbar\r\n' |hd` with `printf 'foo\r\nbar\r\n' |tr -d '\r' |hd`

Answer (score -1):

Below code is removing ^M chars

```
tr -d '\015' < $InptFileName > $InptFileName.tmp
mv $InptFileName.tmp $InptFileName
```